ItexSharp c# mvc
Tengo una aplicacion donde le agrego texto a un archivo pdf que ya tengo previamente, este texto se lo pongo en la parte superior del documento pero al momento de aplicar esta accion el documento pdf en ocasiones aparece que se gira 180 grados.
A alguien le ha pasado algo similar?
Nota: el archivo pdf que tengo o que quiero modificar y agregarle un texto es un archivo escaneado. Cuando noto que se gira lo abro en adobe y le aplico la accion OCR, y cuando le vuelvo a añadir el texto ya no se gira el documento.
Pueden guiarme a que se deba esto?
Gracias.
